# Taylor Expansion of $\frac{x^4}{9+x^3}$ using elementary series

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have exhausted my book of tricks trying to do a series expansion of:
$$f(x)=\frac{x^4}{9+x^3}$$
It is trivial to obtain by taking successive derivatives of the function, but I would like to know whether it is possible to derive using already known expansions. I've tried most the the usual regime of differentiation, integration, algebraic manipulation...etc

Any tips for a starting point would be appreciated (don't ruin the surprise).

Comment: dont know where you want to develop, hopefully not $\pm3i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometric series.

$$\dfrac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots$$

You can find the expansion without taking a single derivative.

Comment: I had the wrong function listed, please see edited post.

Comment: @RichardP: It's okay - you still use geometric series. And you can still find the expansion without taking a single derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Start from $$
\frac1{1+u}=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-u)^n
$$
Then evaluate with $$u = \frac{x^3}9$$and multiply by $\frac{x^4}9$.

Comment: I had the wrong function listed, please see the edited post

Comment: I edited my post also.